# Pyglet and FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyglet

I've been trying to play videos with python by using the piglet library. After installation, I tried the video.py in the examples folder. The following error occurred : "pyglet.media.sources.riff.WAVEFormatException: FFmpeg is required to decode compressed media". FFmpeg and AVBin are both installed on my computer. How can I make piglet work ?

Comment: If it's a windows computer, maybe ffmpeg.exe is required in the directory of the code.

Comment: Check your system $PATH variable. It seems like your system can't find FFmpeg application. Find where FFmpeg is located, and add that location to the end of your $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/ah2I54BSrZg

You can install FFmpeg for your platform by following the instructions found in the FFmpeg download page.

For Mac OS and Linux, the library is usually installed system-wide. For Windows users, it’s not recommended to install the library in one of the windows sub-folders.

Instead we recommend to use the pyglet.options search_local_libs:

`import pyglet
pyglet.options['search_local_libs'] = True`

This will allow pyglet to find the FFmpeg binaries in the lib folder located in your running script folder.